# Simplest URL rewrite rule not working in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to run following dummy URL rewrite rule, but every time I'm adding it nothing happens:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.jpg)$ $1    
</IfModule>
```

Is there anything wrong with above rule ?

Comment: You rule is not doing anything. What URL are you entering and what behavior do you expect?

Comment: @anubhava No, you are right, but any other rules is not working too. I updated my answer

Comment: @anubhava look at this question too, its related: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79536/get-access-to-images-with-2-different-urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule is pointless - you check in the RewriteCond if file doesn't exists and if so you try make redirect to the not existing file.
mod_rewrite is smart enough to prevent that cand of rewriting  hell, he is checking if uri after your RewriteRule doesn't changed, and if so he just ignoring this RewriteRule. So your RewriteRule **must** modify original uri or it will be ignored.

Comment: So RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f mean if file not exists ?